# Images not Cropped to correct size

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, crop

This jquery script can crop any image to correct size by tweaking the image url. This is the only Jquery script in web i have found for *crop image of specific div/elements*. Problem is suddenly the script is not able to crop image to correct size, the script's width-height variable is `var w = 200` and `var h = 150` but problem is **width** variable is not working, cropped images height and width became the same size. Means only height variable works, output cropped image became **150px** X **150px**. *It should 200px X 150px.*

**JS:**

```
var w = 200;
var h = 150;
$('.crop').find('img').each(function(n, image){
  var image = $(image);
  image.attr({src : image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'s' + w + '-h' + h +'-c')});
  image.attr('width',w);
  image.attr('height',h);
 });
```

Problem [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r7fyqxpa/4/) >

**NOTE:** I'm using Latest chrome and it's not working, Version 43.0.2357.130 and also not work in latest Firefox. And please see the original size using Inspect element [Shift+Ctrl+I] or download the cropped image.

I have not able to find any reason/problem why Images not Crop to correct size? and what is the solution? please help :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's wrong using {} inside attr()

Comment: @Bhojendra Nepal  What i should do? Fiddle please.

Comment: `image.attr('src' , image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'s' + w + '-h' + h +'-c'));`

Comment: @Bhojendra Nepal  Thanks, but not working, please see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r7fyqxpa/5/

Comment: what's not working? Sorry, but I'm not clever at regex. anything else I would help you.

Comment: @Aabira Take a look at my answer, is it what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29635418/crop-image-to-correct-size-by-tweaking-the-image-url), and make some test,

then I find out that `s200-h150-c` seems weird

So I replace

`image.attr({src : image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'s' + w + '-h' + h +'-c')});`

to

`image.attr({src : image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'w' + w + '-h' + h +'-c')});`

With `s200-h150-c` become `w200-h150-c`, and it works. Not sure there's typo on origin post or the function changed.

```js
var w = 200;
var h = 150;
$('.crop').find('img').each(function(n, image){
  var image = $(image);
  image.attr('src' , image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'w' + w + '-h' + h +'-c'));
  image.attr('width',w);
  image.attr('height',h);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Please save the croped Image for see the actual result.
<br/><br/>
1) After Crop (Result: 150px X 150px ) 
<br><br>
<div class="crop">
<img src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-R7XPICyjSZA/VRaUCQteV1I/AAAAAAAABLc/PSsERo55dIg/s1600/artworks-000103151765-uxzfpd-t500x500.jpg"/>
</div>
<br/><br/>
2) After Crop (Result: 150px X 150px )
<br/><br/>
<div class="crop">
<img src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-YTDvE4-4L0o/VIkaNloCRCI/AAAAAAAAAu0/8Q0MkvJyGZE/s1600/pc-type65756.jpg"/>
</div>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using curly braces `{ }` inside the attr method which is not allowed to use because [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr) doesn't accept object `{}` as a parameter.

So, you can change to:

```
image.attr({src : image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'s' + w + '-h' + h +'-c')});
```

With this:

```
image.attr('src' , image.attr('src').replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'s' + w + '-h' + h +'-c'));
```

---

But better solution would be using like this:

```
image.attr('src' , function(i,v){
   return v.replace(/s\B\d{2,4}/,'s' + w + '-h' + h +'-c'));
});
```

---

And you can use [css](http://api.jquery.com/css) for setting width and height like this:

```
image.css({'width':w,'height':h});
```

Comment: I meant to use css() method of jquery. And sorry, couldn't create/see a jsfiddle as my internet connection is very slow.

Comment: - Thanks please give Fiddle.

Comment: Ok dear, thaks for your try.